Configure Secondary Click as Right Click for Guest Users by default
How do we enable Secondary Click (Right Click) for Guest Users by default?
I know I can change the settings of an existing account with this command:
/usr/bin/defaults write /Users/<USER HOME>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist Button2 -int 2

However, the guest account has no files in its home folder, as the data will be wiped every time it logs out. How can I configure the Secondary Click as Right Click for the Guest account?
p.s. there is no Guest User Template in:
/Library/User Templates/

